# How to prevent the request object from being cached in Django

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I am using memcached for caching in my django project and I have view like this

```
def questions(request):
    # code to fetch all questions
```

The function does nothing other than return a list of questions from the database, however to the page that it renders the result has a header in which I show the request.user name.

If I directly use `@cache_page` decorator then the request object is also getting cached and the `request.user` on that page is also fetched from the cache. As a result I am seeing someone else's name when I go to the questions page.

Is there a way that I can prevent the request object from getting cached, using a decorator. One way is to use the low level api and cache the querysets that I want to cache, but is it possible to write a decorator that will not cache anything related to the request object?

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Think about modify template for you page, so you can cache one block based on user

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 500 sidebar request.user.username %}
    .. sidebar for logged in user ..
{% endcache %}
```

and other block was the same for all users

```
{% cache 500 questions %}
    .. questions list ..
{% endcache %}
```

Take a look at [Django Template fragment caching docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#template-fragment-caching)

Comment: Yes this is a possible solution, but then it means changing in a lot of templates, and what to do if I have to show something user dependent with the questions list itself. So I can't really cache it. That's why I was looking for a more generic solution by excluding the request object from being put in the cache